# Highcharts random realtime with detecting too high value

Tags: graph, highcharts, visualization

I am trying to achieve something which will look like the following image. I want two things:

[image]

1: the *background color* to a certain *value* (for this example 0.5) should be colored differently.
2: anything that goes above that mark should be in a different color.

Is this possible?

What i have so far is really basic:
http://jsfiddle.net/t21m44tv/

```
backgroundColor: {
  stops: [
    [0, 'rgb(245, 245, 245)'],
    [1, 'rgb(245, 245, 245)']
  ]
},
```

Comment: Could you please post your image again?

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński did :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use yAxis plotBands for adding the background color to a certain value:

```
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: ''
    },
    plotLines: [{
      value: 0,
      width: 0,
      color: '#808080'
    }],
    plotBands: [{
      from: 0,
      to: 0.5,
      color: 'rgba(230,120,50,0.2)',
      zIndex: 5
    }]
  },
```

You can use zones for changing the color of your series depending on the value of points:

```
  plotOptions: {
    areaspline: {
      fillOpacity: 0.8,
    },
    series: {
      marker: {
        enabled: false
      },
      zones: [{
        value: 0.5,
        color: '#f7a35c'
      }, {
        color: '#90ed7d'
      }],
      lineWidth: 0
    }
  },
```

Here you can find an example how it can work: 
http://jsfiddle.net/t21m44tv/2/